# UISlider decreases alpha of UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, algorithm, logic

I have `UISlider`. By increasing it's value, it needs to decrease alpha of `UIImage` from 1 to 0 (`UIImage` situated on the same view).
max-min values:

UISlider: 0 - 100

UIImage.alpha = 1 - 0

If I understand right, question is to write an algorhythm, what will set corresponding relations to pairs of values, e.g.: 0,99 - 0,01, 0,98 - 0,02 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

If you want slider value 100 to be alpha 1.0, use:

`valueFromSlider / maxValueOfSlider`

If you want slider value 0 to be alpha 1.0, use:

`1 - (valueFromSlider / maxValueOfSlider)`

### Why does this work?

You're simply getting a percentage of how far along the slider is, and applying that percentage as the alpha (which works in percentages anyway). The second solution that uses `1 - ...` is simply calculating the inverse value.

With this calculation, your `UISlider` can have any range of values, from `0-5` or `0-25000`, and the correct alpha will still be calculated. The only difference being is that you have finer granularity of control of the alpha with the larger range, which makes sense, you have 25000 possible values as opposed to 5 (assuming discrete values, sliders can be continuous).

Comment: This is all excellent information. But it doesn't cover a simple question. Why have the slider be on a different scale than is needed? If the required value is 0.0-1.0, why have a slider on a scale of 0 - 100? To me, it makes sense to fit the slider's model to the target model (the image's alpha). Different scales requires extra, needless, calculations.

Comment: It was the task as it was given to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to leave the slider with the default minimum value of 0.0 and maximum value of 1.0. Then no conversion is needed.

If you need to display the slider's current value as 0 - 100 then multiply the slider's current value by 100.

Comment: but i need to decrease from 1 to 0 alpha of image, not increase from 0 to 1.

Comment: Then you do: `myImage.alpha = 1.0 - mySlider.value`.

Comment: @Alexey Use the inverse (see my answer)